# hash_map questions / tutorial

Tags: c++, hashmap

I know how hashmap works in Java. But I can't fully understand in C++.

I found some simple tutorials, but there are no hashfunctions etc..

Does a string need hash function?

```
hash_map<string, string> hm;
hm.insert(make_pair("one", "two"));
hm.insert(make_pair("three", "four"));
```

how will it work without hash functions for string?
how to add hash func?

Is there any good tutorial for hash_map?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For starters, `hash_map` is not a standard C++ library; it's a compiler extension that ships with Visual Studio and g++.  If you want to use a more standardized hash table in C++, look at either the Boost.Unordered libraries, the TR1 hash containers, or, if you have a more modern compiler, the new C++0x standard hash container types.  These containers, which are named `unordered_map` and `unordered_set` rather than the more suggestive `hash_map` or `hash_set`, have more standardized support and are more portable.

As to your question about how to specify a hash function, the `hash_map` has built-in hash functions for most of the standard types, including `std::string`, and so you don't need to specify one.  If you do want to define your own hash function, you should create a function object that overloads `operator()` to provide a hash code, then parameterize the `hash_map` over that type in addition to the other types.  For example:

```
struct MyCustomHash {
    size_t operator() (const string& str) const {
        /* Terrible hash function... for instructional purposes only! */
        return str.empty()? 0 : str[0];
    }
};

hash_map<string, int, MyCustomHash> myHashMap;
```

Now `myHashMap` will use `MyCustomHash` instead of the default hash function.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In TR1 the hash map is called unordered_map.

Comment: That's an excellent point - I will update the post to mention that.

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to directly call a hash function for string? Something like string s; s.getHash();

Comment: @VextoR- In Java, every object has its own `hashCode` method, but in C++ this is not the case and hash codes are free functions external to any class.  You then invoke the appropriate external function on the object to get the hash code.  If you know what function object is computing the hash code, you can get the hash code directly by writing something like `myHashFunctionObject(myString)` to get the hash code.  But no, there's no simple `.hashCode()`-esque way to do this in C++ that works on all object types.

Comment: In C++0x you can use `std::hash <std::string> () (...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Which hashmap implementation are you using? The one added in C++0x, std::unordered_map, already define hash functions for some types (including strings). If you try to use a hashmap without a hash function it won't compile (the error will occur when you try to insert something).